# How does Doctrine Mongodb work in Symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to manipulate mongodb in symfony and I'm a bit confused how the things work.
The documentation is not very well organised and have a lot of ambiguities such as invoking the word entity where they've never mentioned before. [HERE](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html)

Anyway, I would like to understand how to select a collection and find documents as I used to do with mMongodb, also , when I var_dump the

```
$this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
->getManager()
->getRepository('ngNearBundle:Post');
```

It gives me some infinite piece of code such as

```
object(Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\LoggableCursor)#248 (23) { ["loggerCallable":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Logger\AggregateLogger)#191 (1) { ["loggers":"Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Logger\AggregateLogger":private]=> array(2) { [0]=>.....
```

Please, if you have any good document to refer , tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2 has a bridge to Doctrine but does not provide all the documentation as Doctrine is very much a separate project. Checkout the [official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/).